# How to use Custom Elements with template?

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element, html-templates

I was trying to understand how web components work so I tried to write a small app that I served on a webserver (tested on Chrome which support `rel="import")`:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="import" href="my-app.html" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app />
  </body>
</html>
```

`my-app.html`:

```
<template id="template">
  <div>Welcome to my app!</div>
</template>

<script>
class MyApp extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    const template = document.getElementById("template");
    const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    shadow.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
customElements.define("my-app", MyApp);
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The `<my-app />` tag is not rendered at all in the DOM and I get this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null

What cannot I retrieve the `template` node? What am I doing wrong?

What I would also like to know is if I am allowed to write an HTML document without the boilerplate code (doctype, head, body, ...), because it's meant to describe a component and not an entire document to be used as is. Is it allowed by the HTML5 specs and/or is it correctly interpreted by a majority of browsers?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: be aware the <link rel="import">` is going away and should no longer be used. ES6 Modules are one way to replace it.

Comment: Yes but IMO ES6 modules are used to import JS modules not HTML.

Comment: Right. Meaning that the `<template>` tag in no longer needed for Components. You can create a `render()` function that returns a template literal string that can embed your data or use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/component-build-tools

Comment: It makes me a bit sad. Firstly because I prefer the `.vue` file syntax to the React's component syntax, and secondly because it's not even JSX that the `render()` method returns, it's a template string, which means that there won't be the highlights of the HTML in your IDE and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While inside the template, don't use the `document` global:

```
<template id="template">
  <div>Welcome to my app!</div>
</template>

<script>
class MyApp extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

    // while inside the imported HTML, `currentDocument` should be used instead of `document`
    const currentDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    // notice the usage of `currentDocument`
    const template = currentDocument.querySelector('#template');

    const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    shadow.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
customElements.define("my-app", MyApp);
</script>
```

Plunker demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/USvbddEDWCSotYrHic7n?p=preview

PS: Notes com compatibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815078/1850609), though I assume you know HTML imports are to be deprecated very soon.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Why do HTML imports are to be deprecated though? Will there be something to replace them?

Comment: If you are using chrome, have a look at the console: **[Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more details.** The alternative at the moment is ES Modules. It is more of a pure-javascript solution.

Comment: But how could we continue to import HTML templates?

Comment: More on why here: https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-10-02-webcomponents-v0-deprecations. Mostrly it is because the spec was never uniformly implemented by the major browsers and the community came to a conclusion it was bad before widespread adoption.

Comment: You do want to continue using html templates or are you asking about the "new best" alternative?

Comment: I like Vue.js so I wanted to use natively something that looks like the `.vue` file syntax but if there is a more elegant way to do this I'm all ears.

Comment: I could point some ES Module resources, but I guarantee you using Vue.js will be a better solution (better documentation, more examples online) right now. These web components spec are frequently changing (like HTML imports being deprecated) and, unless you have a hard reason (e.g. stubborn employer) to choose native web components, I'd go Vue.js all the way. Furthermore, if, or when, the web components become really a mature stable standard, there will certainly be ways to generate/migrate web components from vue code.

Comment: @acdcjunior In fact I'm writing an essay on IPFS, which is a protocol meant to replace HTTP and would be completly serverless. I asked myself how to continue to do templating without webservers, and the thing is, even front-end frameworks like Vue or React need a Node server. So that was the reason I wanted to document myself on native solutions like web components.

Comment: Vue/React don't really need a node server. The product of a vue/react app can be just one big `.js` file (aka "bundle") that is imported into the page via a regular `<script>` tag and does and includes everything (even HTML and CSS inlined). Vue/React only REEEALY need a node server if you wish to do server-side rendering, but this feature is, well, not always needed (to say the least).

Comment: Yes I know, especially Vue can be used browser-side, but using components becomes way more complicated. You cannot use `.vue` files on the browser in short.